# How to set value for specific default value of a parameter in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a repost but I have not found the answer yet

Imagine you have the following function:

```
function calculus(a, b = 2, c = 3)  {
   return a + b - c; 
}
```

What I want to do is to pass new values for parameters a and c, without having to edit b as well

so I have written the methods I tried in the following snippet

```js
function calculus(a, b = 2, c = 3) {
  return a + b - c;
}

document.body.append("Case 1: Result " + calculus(2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 2: Result " + calculus(2, 2, 2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Csse 3: Result " + calculus(2, c = 2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
// next line syntax error
//document.body.append("Case 4:" + calculus(2, c : 3))
```

so writing inside the function call "c=2" or "c:2" does not produce the same result as Case 2

is there any syntax that i can use to do that? so to pass only a and c as arguments and omitting b, and still get the same result as Case 2?

if not, what are the workarounds you would use? maybe an object with properties as a parameter?

Comment: `c = 2` inside a function call is just a variable assignment, so you implicitly create a global variable c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass `undefined` for parameters you want to omit:

```js
function calculus(a, b = 2, c = 3) {
  return a + b - c;
}

document.body.append("Case 1: Result " + calculus(2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 2: Result " + calculus(2, 2, 2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 3: Result " + calculus(2, undefined, 2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 4: Result " + calculus(2, undefined, 3))
```

You can also use an array parameter, which allows `[2,,3]` to be passed:

```js
function calculus([a, b = 2, c = 3]) {
  return a + b - c;
}

document.body.append("Case 1: Result " + calculus([2]))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 2: Result " + calculus([2, 2, 2]))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 3: Result " + calculus([2,,2]))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 4: Result " + calculus([2,,3]))
```

An object would work the same way:

```js
function calculus({a, b = 2, c = 3}) {
  return a + b - c;
}

document.body.append("Case 1: Result " + calculus({a: 2}))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 2: Result " + calculus({a: 2, b:2, c:2}))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 3: Result " + calculus({a: 2, c: 2}))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 4: Result " + calculus({a: 2, c: 3}))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe something like "c=2" syntax will be added in the future, because I wanted that the function will require at least the first parameter when you call the function and you start typing the functions args, like linting showing you that the first argument is needed; i assume object/array params will not do that

Answer (score 2):

There is no special syntax for this but instead, but you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this like:

```
calculus( ...[2,,2] )
```

This will pass `a` & `c` as `2` and `b` as `undefined`. So, when `b` is `undefined`, then the default value for `b` be used. Also, know that using `calculus( ...[2,,2] )` is same as doing:

```
calculus( 2, undefined, 2 )
```

Spread syntax `myFunction(...array)` is just a short way to use the same logic here.

```js
function calculus(a, b = 2, c = 3) {
  return a + b - c;
}

document.body.append("Case 1: calculus(2) --> " + calculus(2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 2: calculus(2, 2, 2) --> " + calculus(2, 2, 2))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Csse 3: calculus( ...[2,,2] ) --> " + calculus( ...[2,,2] ))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 4: calculus( ...[2,,3] ) --> " + calculus( ...[2,,3] ))
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.append("Case 5: calculus(2, undefined, 3) --> " + calculus(2, undefined, 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can skip specifying this parameter by specifying 2 commas in turn and wrapping it all in an array

```
calculus([2,,3])
```